# How should the LibGDX dispose() method be used?

Tags: java, libgdx

It is very unclear to me how the `dispose()` method in the LibGDX framework works and should be used. From what I have learned, after you do not need a certain resource, you must dispose to make sure your program runs optimal.

I am working on a mobile application and I have an `AssetManager` that loads all of the required assets at launch, in a special designated Loading Screen. The problem is I don't know when or if I should unload or dispose them.

When I started developing the app, I didn't have the Manager loading all of the assets at the start and it was taking the program too long to load all the assets of a `Screen` every time it was accessed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see `dispose()` method in some classes/Interface of LibGDX API

- `dispose()` method of `ApplicationListener` Interface and of course inside his implemented classes `ApplicationAdapter`, `Game`

  `dispose()` method of `ApplicationListener` is lifecycle method and called when the application is destroyed. Any disposable resources that you created in `create()` method should be destroyed in this method.
- `dispose()` method of `Screen` Interface and his adapter class `ScreenAdapter`

  If you want some resources for particular `Screen` then create that resources in `show()` method and destroy in this `dispose()` method but Screen's `dispose()` not called by `ApplicationListener` lifecycle method so you need to call by yourself. I prefer to call `dispose()` method by `hide()` method of Screen interface.
- `dispose()` method of many classes (like `SpriteBatch`, `Stage`, `AssetManager` and many more..) of LibGDX API.

  In 1<sup>st</sup> and 2<sup>nd</sup> points I use a term `disposable resource`. How I know which is disposable object. In libGDX there is Interface `Disposable`, LibGDX classes use this interface to release resources obtained by some object.
- `dispose()` method of `Disposable` Interface

  Any classes that implement `Disposable` interface need to be disposed.

This is all about `dispose()` method.

---

1. If you're creating large game that needed lots of resources then keeping all in memory is not preferable so you need to unload some resources that you're not using.

   Let's suppose we're creating game having two game play one is `gardening` and one is type of `3 match game`, both game play need lots of resources so when we move from one game play to other, unload previous game play resources from AssetManager and load new game play resources into `AssetManager`.

   You should keep only one object of `AssetManager` in your App and must be dispose in `ApplicationListener`'s `dispose()` method.
2. If you're working on small project/game, you can avoid loading and unloading resources, create object of `AssetManager` once in `create()` method, load required resources and use all over your game and `dispose()` when you exit your game by `dispose()` method of `ApplicationListener`.

Answer (score 4):

Game.dispose() or ApplicationListener.dispose() is called automatically when the game quits.

In those method you dispose things you constantly need like textures,music,sounds or assetManager which holds those objects.

```
class MainClass extends Game....

@Override
public void dispose(){ // this method is called when the game quits
   texture1.dispose();
   music.dispose();
   assetManager.dispose();
}
```

However if you no longer need a object and is disposable you should dispose it when you dont need it no more, an example would be Pixmaps.

```
class MainClass extends Game....

Texture texture;
@Override
public void create(){
    Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(width,height, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888);

    pixmap.setColor(0,0,0,0.5f);
    pixmap.fill();

    texture = new Texture(pixmap);
    pixmap.dispose();

}
```

`Screen`, whenever you dont need a screen, you dispose it

```
class SplashScreen implements Screen....

public void changeScreen(){
   dispose(); //dispose the current screen
   setScreen(new Screen());
}

@Override
public void dispose(){ //this method doesnt get called automatically
  splashTexture.dispose();
}
```

You could instantiate a screen and keep it in memory and dispose it in Game.dispose() though

Comment: So the dispose method in EVERY class is only called when the entire game is shut down, or is it, for example, if you have multiple game states, called when the state is switched?

Comment: No, the only method that gets call automatically is the Game.dispose() method, which is called when the game ends, what do you mean with **every** class? classes that implements `Screen`?